# Crystal Report Date Format Error with CDate and ToText using HH:mm

Tags: crystal-reports

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting a bad date time format exception on the following:

```
Cstr({invsp_SelectOrderWithClient;1.dtLabel1}) + " at " 
  +  ToText(CDate({invsp_SelectOrderWithClient;1.dtLabel1}), "HH:mm")
```

The exception is just generic:

> Bad Date Format string.
>
> Details.errorkind

Not very helpful, it doesn't have anything more specific, however it is pretty generic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong....you are converting to date but extracting time part from the value.

Instead try like this.

```
Cstr({invsp_SelectOrderWithClient;1.dtLabel1}) + " at " 
  +  ToText(CDateTime({invsp_SelectOrderWithClient;1.dtLabel1}), "HH:mm")
```